# Play an audio file of unknown size in browser

Tags: php

I wrote a script that extracts a MIDI file from an archive and runs Timidity to convert it to a wave file. When using `exec()` PHP halts until the program finishes, but I found another way to start Timidity using `pclose(popen('start "title" /b ' . $command_str, 'r'));`. Then the script continues while the file is being converted.

I would like to be able to play the wave file as soon as it becomes available (it usually takes a few seconds to be converted). So instead of setting the `src` attribute of the `<audio>` element to the resulting wave file, I set it to a PHP script which should stream the data as it becomes available:

```
if (isset($_GET['stream']))
 {
  define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024 * 1024);
  $loop = 5; // in case resulting wave file is too small
  while (filesize('tmp.wav') < CHUNK_SIZE && $loop > 0)
   {
    sleep(1);
    $loop--;
   }
  $fpwav_res = fopen('tmp.wav', 'rb');
  if ($fpwav_res === FALSE)
    exit('Could not open temporary wave file.');
  header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
  header('Content-Type: audio/wave');
//  header('Connection: keep-alive');  or  header('Connection: close');
  $offset = 0;
  while ($offset < filesize('tmp.wav'))
   {
    if (fseek($fpwav_res, $offset) === -1)
      exit('Could not seek in temporary wave file.');
    $data_str = fread($fpwav_res, CHUNK_SIZE);
    if ($data_str === FALSE)
      exit('Could not read from temporary wave file');
    echo(sprintf('%X', strlen($data_str)) . PHP_EOL . $data_str . PHP_EOL);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    $offset += CHUNK_SIZE;
    sleep(1); // wait for more data
   }
  fclose($fpwav_res);
  exit('0' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);
 }
```

I'm using all this only for myself (on localhost, Windows desktop, Firefox browser).

I thought I may have to juggle with the values for chunk size and sleep duration to make it work, but as it is, only about 6 seconds play (when I `sleep(1)` before generating the audio element it's 30 seconds). The total duration is always displayed as 6:45:48.

(When I reload the page I have an `if` statement that recognizes that the `filemtime('tmp.wav')` is more than 5 seconds from current time and sets the wave file as audio source. That works as expected.)

**EDIT**: I've played a bit more with it, but it seems fruitless. I will go back to stalling PHP until the file is written.

What I've found:

- The 6 seconds it plays is equal to one chunk (total file size: ~30 MB, total duration: ~3:00 / 180 seconds; 1 MB chunk -> 1/30 * 180 seconds)
- Streaming a fully rendered wave file does not work either. Total duration is never displayed correctly. Playback stopped at certain points for different files: ~1:41/3:01 / ~1:29/2:28. Changing `sleep(1)` to `usleep(300000)` (0.3 instead of 1 second between iterations) did not help.
- Streaming a fully rendered MP3 files **does** work. Total duration is displayed correctly (is it encoded in the file header?). The file plays to the end.
- Same for an OGG file I tested.
- Converting the wave file to MP3 as it is being created by calling to FFMPEG does not seem to work. It only converts what it sees. (Maybe there is an option that I don't know. Maybe if I give the URL to my stream script to FFMPEG ...? Nope!)
- Timidity mentions an option to output to Ogg Vorbis in its manual, but in my binary "Playmode `v' is not compiled in." ... (Compiling the source myself is probably not feasible *for me*. Other MIDI renderers like FluidSynth or WildMIDI do not seem to be able to output MP3 or OGG either.)

Answer (score 0):

One part of the problem is solved pretty easily by looking at the manual for `filesize()`:

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.

So, when adding `clearstatcache();` before the `sleep()` (currently using `usleep()`) commands, it works.

Playing a wave file of unknown size still has the duration quirk, but I also found how to convert directly to an MP3 file using FFMPEG: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Timidity

This necessitated creating a batch file since `popen()` doesn't like the pipe and did wait for the operation to finish. This *may* be remedied by using `proc_open()`, but that function seems rather complicated to me.

As expected, some stuff in regards to chunk size and waiting (especially a cold call is slow) needs to be figured out, but overall it works.